# Seeking HTML editor with visual tag matching

Tags: html-parsing, html-helper

Is there an editor or IDE which will show HTML code with some visual indication of matching open/close tags?

Kompozer sort of helps, but I would prefer something like

```
.---><div>
|
|      <h1>xxx</h1>
|
|  .---><frameset>
|  |
|  |  .---><div>
|  |  |
|  |  |      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
|  |  | 
|  |  .---></div>
|  |
|  .---></frameset>
|
.---></div>
```

which constantly updates as I write my code. The ability to fold inner tags would also be nice.

---

edit: any o/s, or cross-platform.

Comment: +1  any o/s, or cross-platform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What operating system are you targetting?

I program mainly on Windows and I use Notepad++ for most text editing. It supports multiple languages, is fairly light weight and easy to install (has a zipped version which can be extracted to directory and run).

It supports syntax highlighting and code folding for HTML (via a tree/node structure on the left margin).

http://notepad-plus-plus.org/

Answer (score 0):

hmm, for the record, [MyEclipse HTML editor](https://www.genuitec.com/products/myeclipse/learning-center/#outline_) also looks very interesting ...

[image]
<sub>(source: [myeclipseide.com](http://www.myeclipseide.com/documentation/quickstarts/htmleditor/images/htmleditor-main-annot.png))</sub>

---

oops, but it's not free :-(